# Order of nodes in XSL Transformation

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a xml which looks like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Object>
<Data type="plan" name="testAom" id="10">

    <obj class="D" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-1" operation="create" >
        <p name="Active">1</p>
        <p name="Type">CPU</p>
        <p name="StDate">2013-07-27T00:00:00+00:00</p>
        <p name="StpDate">2013-07-29T00:00:00+00:00</p>
    </obj>

    <obj class="E" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-1/E-1" operation="create">
        <p name="dayOfWeek">0</p>
        <p name="interval">10</p>
    </obj>

    <obj class="E" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-2/E-1" operation="update">
        <p name="dayOfWeek">0</p>
        <p name="interval">10</p>
    </obj>

    <obj class="D" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-2" operation="update">
        <p name="Active">1</p>
        <p name="Type">CPU</p>
        <p name="StDate">2013-07-27T00:00:00+00:00</p>
        <p name="StpDate">2013-07-29T00:00:00+00:00</p>
    </obj>
</Data>
</Object>
```

Here the order of the input source file is not guaranteed. But in the output after an XSL transformation, i require the output to be in certain order.

Below is the XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="obj[@class = 'D' ]">
<xsl:variable name="item" select="."/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$item/@operation='update'">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="operation">delete</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="operation">create</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="operation">NEW_create</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="obj[@class = 'E' ]">
<xsl:variable name="childitem" select="."/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$childitem/@operation='update'">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="operation">delete</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="operation">create</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="operation">NEW_create</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>         
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output i get is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Object>
<Data type="plan" name="testAom" id="10">

    <obj class="D" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-1" operation="NEW_create">
        <p name="Active">1</p>
        <p name="Type">CPU</p>
        <p name="StDate">2013-07-27T00:00:00+00:00</p>
        <p name="StpDate">2013-07-29T00:00:00+00:00</p>
    </obj>

    <obj class="E" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-1/E-1" operation="NEW_create">
        <p name="dayOfWeek">0</p>
        <p name="interval">10</p>
    </obj>

    <obj class="E" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-2/E-1" operation="delete">
        <p name="dayOfWeek">0</p>
        <p name="interval">10</p>
    </obj>
    <obj class="E" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-2/E-1" operation="create">
        <p name="dayOfWeek">0</p>
        <p name="interval">10</p>
    </obj>

    <obj class="D" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-2" operation="delete">
        <p name="Active">1</p>
        <p name="Type">CPU</p>
        <p name="StDate">2013-07-27T00:00:00+00:00</p>
        <p name="StpDate">2013-07-29T00:00:00+00:00</p>
    </obj>
    <obj class="D" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-2" operation="create">
        <p name="Active">1</p>
        <p name="Type">CPU</p>
        <p name="StDate">2013-07-27T00:00:00+00:00</p>
        <p name="StpDate">2013-07-29T00:00:00+00:00</p>
    </obj>
</Data>
</Object>
```

Here when the **operation** attribute is **"update"**, i need to do a delete and create.

The nodes above  have a parent child relationship based on attribute **distName**, ie **A-1/B-1/C-1/D-1** is parent of **A-1/B-1/C-1/D-1/E-1**.
For the update operation to work correct, i need the parent create and delete first and then followed by child delete and create always.

**How can this be achieved irrespective of the order of input source xml file??**

ie. obj nodes with class attribute **D** should be first in order than **E**.

Expected Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Object>
<Data type="plan" name="testAom" id="10">
<obj class="D" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-1" operation="NEW_create">
<p name="Active">1</p>
<p name="Type">CPU</p>
<p name="StDate">2013-07-27T00:00:00+00:00</p>
<p name="StpDate">2013-07-29T00:00:00+00:00</p>
</obj>
<obj class="E" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-1/E-1" operation="NEW_create">
<p name="dayOfWeek">0</p>
<p name="interval">10</p>
</obj>
<obj class="D" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-2" operation="delete">
<p name="Active">1</p>
<p name="Type">CPU</p>
<p name="StDate">2013-07-27T00:00:00+00:00</p>
<p name="StpDate">2013-07-29T00:00:00+00:00</p>
</obj><obj class="D" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-2" operation="create">
<p name="Active">1</p>
<p name="Type">CPU</p>
<p name="StDate">2013-07-27T00:00:00+00:00</p>
<p name="StpDate">2013-07-29T00:00:00+00:00</p>
</obj>
<obj class="E" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-2/E-1" operation="delete">
<p name="dayOfWeek">0</p>
<p name="interval">10</p>
</obj><obj class="E" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-2/E-1" operation="create">
<p name="dayOfWeek">0</p>
<p name="interval">10</p>
</obj>
</Data>
</Object>
```

Comment: You've given us a non-working stylesheet and its undesirable results, but you haven't shown us what the desirable results are for your given sample input.

Comment: Hi Ken, I have corrected my question and have updated with desirable results needed..

Comment: Will you need to cope with class attributes of A, B and C?

Comment: Yes.... There can be any class...

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something in your requirements, but if not, then an update is simply a delete and a create and can be done in a single template.  I focused my solution on the action, not on the class.  I think my stylesheet produces exactly what you asked to be produced, but it may not be doing what you want.  I hope it helps.

```
t:\ftemp>type objects.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Object>
<Data type="plan" name="testAom" id="10">

    <obj class="D" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-1" operation="create" >
        <p name="Active">1</p>
        <p name="Type">CPU</p>
        <p name="StDate">2013-07-27T00:00:00+00:00</p>
        <p name="StpDate">2013-07-29T00:00:00+00:00</p>
    </obj>

    <obj class="E" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-1/E-1" operation="create">
        <p name="dayOfWeek">0</p>
        <p name="interval">10</p>
    </obj>

    <obj class="E" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-2/E-1" operation="update">
        <p name="dayOfWeek">0</p>
        <p name="interval">10</p>
    </obj>

    <obj class="D" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-2" operation="update">
        <p name="Active">1</p>
        <p name="Type">CPU</p>
        <p name="StDate">2013-07-27T00:00:00+00:00</p>
        <p name="StpDate">2013-07-29T00:00:00+00:00</p>
    </obj>
</Data>
</Object>
t:\ftemp>call xslt objects.xml objects.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Object>

   <Data type="plan" name="testAom" id="10">
      <obj class="D" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-1" operation="New_create">
         <p name="Active">1</p>
         <p name="Type">CPU</p>
         <p name="StDate">2013-07-27T00:00:00+00:00</p>
         <p name="StpDate">2013-07-29T00:00:00+00:00</p>
      </obj>
      <obj class="E" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-1/E-1" operation="New_create">
         <p name="dayOfWeek">0</p>
         <p name="interval">10</p>
      </obj>
      <obj class="D" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-2" operation="delete">
         <p name="Active">1</p>
         <p name="Type">CPU</p>
         <p name="StDate">2013-07-27T00:00:00+00:00</p>
         <p name="StpDate">2013-07-29T00:00:00+00:00</p>
      </obj>
      <obj class="D" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-2" operation="create">
         <p name="Active">1</p>
         <p name="Type">CPU</p>
         <p name="StDate">2013-07-27T00:00:00+00:00</p>
         <p name="StpDate">2013-07-29T00:00:00+00:00</p>
      </obj>
      <obj class="E" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-2/E-1" operation="delete">
         <p name="dayOfWeek">0</p>
         <p name="interval">10</p>
      </obj>
      <obj class="E" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/C-1/D-2/E-1" operation="create">
         <p name="dayOfWeek">0</p>
         <p name="interval">10</p>
      </obj>
   </Data>

</Object>
t:\ftemp>type objects.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Object/Data">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <!--results are in distName order-->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="obj">
      <xsl:sort select="@distName"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--for creation, only the attribute changes, nothing else-->
<xsl:template match="obj[@operation='create']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="operation">New_create</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--remove those marked for deletion-->
<xsl:template match="obj[@operation='delete']"/>

<!--remove and recreate those marked for update-->
<xsl:template match="obj[@operation='update']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="operation">delete</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="operation">create</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
t:\ftemp>rem Done!
```

Comment: Hi Ken, How to handle above xsl if the xml is associated with a xmlns="xyz.xsd".. i was not able to get how to use it then?

Comment: That's no different than with any namespace attached to the input elements, just use the usual approach of adding a prefix for the namespace to the element names in your stylesheet.